# Openerp : No transition between stages in opportunities

Tags: odoo

I'm using Openerp 7.

In opportunities, in form view, I don't the the five stages that are set.

For exemple : If I create a new one, it has just one stage "New". From the kanban view, if I drag & drop this opportunity to a other stage, "negotiation", it still has only one stage(negotiation)

I don't know why the possibility to escalate the stage from the form view disappeared.

Could someone help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: OK i found the solution.

After activating developer mode.

In form view of the opportunities, i select the "Edit FormView" (on the upper left of the screen)

I replace

<field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" clickable="True"/>

By

<field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" clickable="True" domain="['&', '|', ('case_default', '=', True), ('section_ids', '=', section_id), '|', ('type', '=', type), ('type', '=', 'both')]" on_change="onchange_stage_id(stage_id)"/>

Comment: Kindly add this as answer & accept it, so that it doesn't get in the unanswered queue

Answer (score 0):

The different steps appear after assigning it to a sales team.  The steps are dependent on the sales team selected.